# Creation of a File

Tags: c#, io, win-universal-app

I have created simple UWP application, where I simply want to store serialized data to a file, which can be accessed later (when user reopens the application after a while).

The place, where I want to store the file is the current installed location and my serialization code looks like following:

```cs
private void SerializeData()
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<MyTask>));
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(installedLocation.Path,sFileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
        try
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, sData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

This is `MyTask` model:

```cs
public class MyTask:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

The error that I've been getting is `UnauthorizedAccessException`. I remember that when I was creating my regular Windows 7 apps under WPF, I had no problem with permission. This is my first UWP app, and therefore I might have forgotten to do something with permissions.

The questions is - is it possible to store simple file in installed directory, or do I need to store all my data files under some *Shared* location?

Answer (score 2):

*Package.InstalledLocation* is a place where your app is installed and it's *read-only* - so you cannot write files there. Use [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) instead - this is the folder where your app should store local data. For more info how to store (and where), please take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Apps can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities.

The locations that all apps can access

When you create a new app, you can access the following file system locations by default:
Application install directory. The folder where your app is installed on the user’s system.
There are two primary ways to access files and folders in your app’s install directory:

1. You can retrieve a StorageFolder that represents your app's install directory, like this:

   ```
   Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
   ```
2. You can retrieve a file directly from your app's install directory by using an app URI, like this:

   ```
   using Windows.Storage;
   StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///file.txt");
   ```

The app's install directory is a read-only location. You can’t gain access to the install directory through the file picker.
Application data locations. The folders where your app can store data. These folders (local, roaming and temporary) are created when your app is installed.
There are two primary ways to access files and folders from your app’s data locations:
Use ApplicationData properties to retrieve an app data folder.
For example, you can use ApplicationData.LocalFolder to retrieve a StorageFolder that represents your app's local folder like this:

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

you can retrieve a file directly from your app's local folder by using an app URI, like this:

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt");
```

User’s Downloads folder:

```
using Windows.Storage;
StorageFile newFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("file.txt");
```

and much much more ... for further reference goto [dev.windows.com](http://dev.windows.com) and you will get a ton of resources.